# How can I store results of SQL query in a variable?

Tags: c#, ado.net

If you take a look at the code below, you'll see I'm looping through a list of queries and outputting the query with the result.

I'd like to be able to store what's currently being output to a variable or list that I can put in the body of an smtp email. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.SetWindowSize(170, 60);

    List<string> queryList = new List<string>(new string[]
    {
        "query 1",
        "query 2",
        "query 3"
    });

    foreach (string query in queryList)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection String");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(query  + Environment.NewLine + "{0}", reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Just as you have used a list to store the queries to be executed, at the same way you could use a list to store the results of the queries

Comment: You could try using a `StringBuilder`. Just append each record in a format that makes sense.

Comment: declare a variable outside of the `foreach`, IE: `var results = new List<string>()` (or whatever you want) then of using `Console.WriteLine` add it to the results variable.

Comment: These are the basics of programming. Read a book or some documentation. It will you better than the off the shelf answer you get here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
private static void Main()
{
    var queryResults = new List<string>();

    foreach (string query in queryList)
    {
        ...

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(query  + Environment.NewLine + "{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                queryResults.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    ...
}
```

You can use `queryResults` later for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you have used a list to store the queries to be executed, at the same way you could use a list to store the results of the queries

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string query in queryList)
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
         connection.Open();
         using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(query + Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                results.Add(query + Environment.NewLine + "No rows found";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to apply the correct using statement around the disposable objects used to query your database. Also, knowing a little more about your query could result in a better approach creating a batch of commands to pass to the database engine and retrieving the results using the [NextResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `SqlDataReader`

For example, supposing that your queries are something like this:

```
 SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE1
 SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE2
 SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE3
```

then you could try to join together the strings in this way (removing the foreach loop and the multiple connection, commands and datareader instances)

```
 string queries = string.Join(";", queryList.ToArray());
 using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
 using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
 {
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                results.Add(query)
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            else
                results.Add(query + Environment.NewLine + "No rows found);
        }
        while (dr.NextResult());
    }
}
```